# Difference between y<count & y<=count

Tags: ruby

I am doing Chris Pine's 'Learn to Program'. The exercise in Ch.11 asks to create a shuffled playlist. Below is what I wrote:

```
def shuffle songs
  playlist = []
  x = 0
  y = 0
  count = songs.length

  while y <= count
    x = rand(count)
    if songs[x] != 'used'
      playlist.push songs[x]
      songs[x] = 'used'
      y= y + 1
    end
  end
  filename = '/Users/M/Music/shuffled_playlist8.m3u'
  File.open filename, 'w' do |s|
    s.puts playlist
  end
end
song_name = Dir['/Users/M/Music/*.{MP3,mp3}']
shuffle song_name
```

In ln7, when I put `<=` instead of `<`, the program won't quit. It may have something to do with the method `rand`, which does not randomize inclusively, or the range of an array starts from `0`. Can somebody point out what leads to the program not quiting?

Comment: What is the difference between "less than" and "less than or equal to"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting 'y' at 0 and incrementing it each time you find a new unused song (which is then marked as used), the maximum value that 'y' could ever obtain is 'count'.

So the while loop will continue forever since it will always satisfy the <= 'count' condition.

Using the < comparison is the correct way to achieve what you are looking to do here, since once 'y == count', you have created the playlist that contains each song from the original array exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

`y` will always be less than or equal to `count` and will never a value greater than `count`. This is because you are starting at `y = 0` and when all the songs are used your `y` is just equal to `count`.

For example if there is just one song, that song will be used in the first loop,
 your `y = 1` and your `count = 1`.
 y will never increase after that. So your loop will never end if your condition is `y <= count`

You will loop unnecessary number of times with the random loop using this method. A better way would be to reduce the `x` given to `rand()`dynamically and removing the used song from the list, so that a repetition of the same condition won't occur again.

```
def shuffle songs
  playlist = []

  while songs.length > 0
    x = rand(songs.length)
    playlist.push songs[x]
    songs.delete_at(x)
  end
  playlist
end
song_name = ("a".."e").to_a
shuffle song_name # => ["d", "c", "a", "b", "e"]
```

or in a single line , using the builtin `shuffle` function

```
song_name = ("a".."e").to_a
song_name.shuffle # => ["e", "c", "b", "a", "d"]
```